# How to get user information after subscription?

Tags: javascript, paypal

I can get user information after normal purchase.

```js
paypal.Buttons({
  createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [{
        amount: {
          value: '0.01'
        }
      }]
    });
  },
  onApprove: function (data, actions) {
    console.log(data)
    return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
      console.log(details) // OK
    })
  }
}).render('#paypal-button-container')
```

However, it cannot be obtained after the subscription.

```js
paypal.Buttons({
  createSubscription: function (data, actions) {
    console.log(data)
    return actions.subscription.create({
      'plan_id': PP_PLAN_ID
    })
  },
  onApprove: function (data, actions) {
    console.log(data)
    return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
      console.log(details) // NG
    })
  }
}).render('#paypal-button-container')
```

How can I use code to get user information?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think PayPal Subscriptions was created with a lot of client-side activity in mind, so you probably need this server-side API call: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_get

(To pull the information into client-side, you would do an `fetch(` XHR to your server.  The demo pattern for normal purchases may be useful as a reference: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server )

Comment: Was that so too.
I need to develop an API.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for display subscription detail while calling the PayPal button code.

```
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
    style: {
        shape: 'pill',
        color: 'blue',
        layout: 'vertical',
        label: 'subscribe'
    },
    createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.subscription.create({
          plan_id: 'P-1DF9508450687805KMCJ5I6A'
        });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {        
        actions.subscription.get().then(function (Details){
          console.log(Details);          
        });
      }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container-');
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's good practice on StackOverflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work.