# Paypal create subscription onApproval GET times out

Tags: json, paypal, timeout, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to access the response json after creating a subscription in Paypal.

This is the code - it uses the Paypal javascript SDK (it is derived from the SDK documentation and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59609198/how-to-get-user-information-after-subscription)):

```
   createSubscription: function (data, actions) {
   return actions.subscription.create({
      'plan_id': 'xxx'
      });
   },

   onApprove: function (data, actions) {
      return actions.subscription.get().then(function (details) {
                        console.log(details)
   });

},
```

The subscription is created ok but the onApprove actions.subscription.get() line times out with the console message:

b.sbox.stats.paypal.com/v2/counter.cgi?p=uid_xxx&s=SMART_PAYMENT_BUTTONS:1 GET https://b.sbox.stats.paypal.com/v2/counter.cgi?p=uid_xxx&s=SMART_PAYMENT_BUTTONS net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Am I using the right code to get the json?  If so, why is it timing out?

EDIT:  After searching the Paypal community again I altered the code as follows:

```
return actions.subscription.get(data.subscriptionID).then(function (details) {
console.log(details)
```

});

Which results in a slightly different error message:

b.sbox.stats.paypal.com/v2/counter.cgi?p=uid_bf756f1ba7_mdg6ntk6mjm&s=SMART_PAYMENT_BUTTONS:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Answer (score 1):

For Subscriptions, there's no reason to do a 'get' in onApprove. Use the information you already have in `data`.

Since onApprove is client-side and occurs after a subscription has been activated, no business critical logic should depend on this code path being executed, since it may not.

If you have anything that must execute, set up a [webhook listener](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions) for BILLING.PLAN.ACTIVATED (plan creation) and/or PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED (a payment occurs)

Comment: Thanks for responding, Preston.  I can't see subscriber name or email in the data object - this is what I need to save them re-entering this info on the next page after a successful payment.  On a straight order rather than a subscription this approach works fine - and the SDK documentation for new subscription shows the required info in the response json.

Comment: Use a webhook to ensure the information is sent directly to your server.

Comment: With a "straight order" integration, no transaction takes place until the capture (which can be done synchronously server-side) -- but this is not true for subscriptions, and so webhooks are the only guaranteed notification.

Comment: Hi Preston - the Paypal subscription API/SDK documentation is not clear on the sequence of events you descibe so I really appreciate you taking the time to help.  If I understand what you are saying, the subscription approval event is separate from, and precedes, the payment event.  The latter is asynchronous and so I need a lstener for this (which I will add, with associated follow-up).

Comment: However, the business logic I am trying to capture here is the approval of the subscription, not the payment.  Setting up the account (username, password &c) has to be done by the user and my preference is that this is done immediately, while they are in the moment.  My interpretation of the API documentation is that this successful subscription information should be there in a json.   I suppose I could have a separate GET to go and retrieve the subsciber info - but this is what I thought the code above is supposed to do.

Comment: As it stands I am simply not pre-filling the account setup form so they must type it in - not the end of the world but less slick than I would like.